# Add parameters on XML node via PHP on SOAP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I'm currently working on a SOAP webservice. It worked well until i had to deal with a request that need the following structure :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
   <ns1:AuthenticationHeader soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next"
soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="www.example.com/soapheader">
      <ns1:ClientName>xxxxx</ns1:ClientName>
      <ns1:WorkingClientName>xxxxx</ns1:WorkingClientName>
      <ns1:UserName>xxxxx</ns1:UserName>
      <ns1:Password>xxxxx</ns1:Password>
   </ns1:AuthenticationHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
   <CreateContactRequest xmlns="http://www.example.com/xxxxx/contactmsgs">
      <Contact xsi:type="ns2:B2CContact" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/xxxxx/contactdata">
         <ns2:Phone></ns2:Phone>
         <ns2:MobilePhone></ns2:MobilePhone>
         <ns2:Email>b@b.com</ns2:Email>
         <ns2:AddressIds>
            <ns2:addressId>xxxxx</ns2:addressId>
         </ns2:AddressIds>
         <ns2:Attributes>
            <ns2:ContactAttribute>
               <ns2:AttributeKey>xxxxxxx</ns2:AttributeKey>
               <ns2:AttributeValue>xxxxxxx</ns2:AttributeValue>
            </ns2:ContactAttribute>
         </ns2:Attributes>
      </Contact>
   </CreateContactRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My problem here, is the xsi:type="ns2:B2CContact" attribute on the "Contact" node. I can't figure out how to have it working. Let me explain a bit:

I defined my header first, with the namespace and authentication param. This part works well.

But when i use the CreateContact() method (Whitch i give the right params) i get the following error :

**Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] Unmarshalling Error: cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'ns1:B2CContact' to a type definition for element 'ns2:CreateContactRequest'**

So, in order to have this, i send the following request : 
I tried everything, SoapVar as you can see below, without soapvar etc..

```
$urlContact = "urlofmyWSDLfile";
$ClientOption = array('trace' => 1);
$ns = "http://www.example.com/soapheader";

$ClientName = "clientname";
$WorkingClientName = "clientname";
$username = "";
$password = "";

$soapParameters = array('ClientName' => $ClientName, 'WorkingClientName' => 
                         $WorkingClientName, 'UserName' => $username, 
                        'Password' => $password);

$header = new SoapHeader($ns, 'AuthenticationHeader', $soapParameters);

$contactService = new SoapClient($urlContact, $ClientOption);
$contactService->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$ContactCriteria = array();
$encoded = new SoapVar($ContactCriteria, XSD_ANYTYPE, "B2CContact", "url of my namespace");
$contact = $contactService->CreateContact($encoded);
$request = $contactService->__getLastRequest();
```

i'm relatively new to SOAP webservices and i'm out of ideas of how to solve this, i search everywhere to find an answer to this but i found nothing... any help is very welcome !
Thanks, 
Maxime